# Android Preference Default Values

Tags: android, default-value, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, listpreference

I have a preference activity which contains a checkbox and a list preference. The main activity of this application gets the current value of the list preference and uses it as the url to gain data from. My problem is that on a fresh install the default value is not being set, thus the value being null and the app instantly crashes before being able to get to the preference screen. Any fixes??

CODE:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSlideMenuItemClickListener {
private SlideMenu slidemenu;
private final static int News = 1;
private final static int Library = 2;
private final static int Photos = 3;
private final static int Videos = 4;
private final static int Maps = 5;
private final static int Prefs = 6;
private final static int About = 7;
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_settings_layout);
    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    tracker.startNewSession("UA-35087731-1", 10, this);
    Typeface blockFonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"FUTURAM.TTF");
    TextView lblTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar); 
    lblTitle.setText("Preferences");
    lblTitle.setTypeface(blockFonts);


          ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("news_feed");
            if(listPreference.getValue()==null) {

                    listPreference.setValueIndex(1);
                final CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("french");

                checkboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {            
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                        if(newValue.toString().equals("true")) {
                            ListPreference newsPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("news_feed");

                            String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.newsfeedfr);
                                    newsPref.setEntryValues(values);
                                    newsPref.setDefaultValue(values[1]);

                        }
                        else {
                            ListPreference news2Pref = (ListPreference) findPreference("news_feed");                                
                            String[] values2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.newsfeed);                                     news2Pref.setEntryValues(values2);                                  news2Pref.setDefaultValue(values2[1]);

                        }      
                        return true;
                    }
            }); }
}
    }
```

---

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = 
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
     URL= sharedPrefs.getString("news_feed", "N/A");
        if(URL==null) {
            URL = "http://scout.org/rss/feed/all";
        }
```

And this is how I retrieve the value in the News Class

---

**LOGCAT OUTPUT**

```
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305): Activity org.scouts.android.news.News has  leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44eb8558 that was originally added here
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity org.scouts.android.news.News has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44eb8558 that was originally added here
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at org.scouts.android.news.News$MyAsyncgTask.onPreExecute(News.java:171)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at org.scouts.android.news.News.onCreate(News.java:100)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-08 00:52:06.569: E/WindowManager(305):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 00:52:35.980: I/Process(305): Sending signal. PID: 305 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace and/or logs?

Comment: Not sure why you need to `setContentView(R.layout.show_settings_layout);` in your `onCreate()`.

Comment: @Wenhui, it contains objects for libraries i am using, BTW The preference activity is not the first run, it is only run if the user runs it. The first run is the news class.

Comment: PreferencesActivity already call `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`, if you `setContentView`, it will override the view in PreferencesActivity. Your error log shows windows leak because `setContentView` override the default view, and the default view isn't been properly deleted. Not sure why you want to do something like this, but you may want to create two separate activities.

Comment: @Wenhui have a look at the complete preference activity code: http://pastebin.com/MU8jrN20, the app DOES work when I put into airplane mode so it doesn't parse data then open prefs and choose value.

Comment: @SquiresSquire Don't know what is wrong. You logcat shows you activity has Dialog windows leak, but I don't see you are using Dialog anywhere. Not sure how to help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17679/discussion-between-squiressquire-and-wenhui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a little silly, but in the line

> URL= sharedPrefs.getString("news_feed", "N/A");

it return N/A for the value, when there is no user selected one, instead of null hence the fix being

> URL= sharePrefs.getString("news_feed", null);